# QBFC InvoiceAddReq update custom fields like Contract, B-Day and Spouse's Name using C#

Tags: c#, quickbooks, qbfc

I am developing one invoice inserting C# application for QuickBooks Pro 2013 with QBFC 10 using C#. In that I want to update few custom fields for each invoice with different values, the fields are 'Contract #', 'B-Day' and 'Spouse's Name' these are related to customers. Please check my post in the intuitdeveloper forum for the same with more details.

I am getting error:

> There was an error when saving a data extension named "Contract #".  QuickBooks error message: The attribute definition for an attribute could not be found. The definition must exist before associated attributes can be created."

https://intuitdeveloper.lc.intuit.com/questions/1267149

Comment: Please post your qbXML request. We can not help you if you don't post the request you're sending to QuickBooks.

Comment: Request XML:
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?qbxml version="10.0"?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRq onError = "stopOnError">
<DataExtAddRq requestID = "0">
<DataExtAdd>
<OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
<DataExtName>OriginName</DataExtName>
<TxnDataExtType>Invoice</TxnDataExtType>
<TxnID>1B04B-1513361148</TxnID>
<DataExtValue>Florida Coast Equip</DataExtValue>
</DataExtAdd>
</DataExtAddRq>
</QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
Error:
There was an error when saving a data extension named "Contract #".  QuickBooks error message: The attribute definition for an attribute could not be found.

Comment: Please check this link for more details https://intuitdeveloper.lc.intuit.com/questions/1267149

Comment: Please edit your question and add the additional details.